# Assessing files hidden by mounting file-system

Tags: ubuntu, partition

I am using Ubutnu 18.04.

Currently, `/home` is mounted on `/` on an NVME disk according to `df` command:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/nvme0n1p2  137G  113G   18G  87% /
...
```

The size of `/dev/sda1` is 400GB which I want to use as my /home according to `fdisk -l`:

```
Device          Start        End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sda1  1172275200 1953523711 781248512 372.5G Linux filesystem
```

Using the guides, I have to find the UUID of `/dev/sda1` using `blkid`

```
/dev/sda1: UUID="3ce518e8-955d-4b26-9dde-c3819d5906d6" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="08f6658f-7432-4a48-bdbd-0ee8f16d9b91"
```

and define the appropriate entry in `/etc/fstab`. So, the content of that is now

```
$ cat /etc/fstab 
UUID=3ce518e8-955d-4b26-9dde-c3819d5906d6   /home    ext4    defaults   0   2
UUID=918a1f7d-b27c-4b82-8a10-ba0d622a37dd /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
UUID=BA35-0600  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1

UUID=36a37d03-0ba7-4196-83ed-876e2782297e none            swap    sw              0       0
```

After running `sudo mount -a`, I see that my home folder becomes empty and all files are disappeared.

```
$ ls /home/mahmood/
$
```

My previous files are missing however, they exist. Since the usage of `/` in `df -h` has not been changed.

Any quick solution?

{UPDATE}

I tired to remount the old partition in `/home2` according to the comments. So, I entered `sudo mkdir /home2 && chmod -R 777 /home2`. Then I edited `/etc/fstab` to keep old and new partitions

```
UUID=3ce518e8-955d-4b26-9dde-c3819d5906d6   /home    ext4    defaults   0   2
/dev/nvme0n1p2 /home2 ext4 defaults 0 2
```

After running `sudo mount -a`, I see:

```
$ ls /
bin    dev   home2           lib    libx32      mnt   root  snap  tmp  vmlinuz
boot   etc   initrd.img      lib32  lost+found  opt   run   srv   usr
cdrom  home  initrd.img.old  lib64  media       proc  sbin  sys   var
$ ls /home
DEBIAN  mahmood  virtualbox-6.0_6.0.0-127566-Ubuntu-bionic_amd64.deb  vt  win7.vdi
$ ls /home2/
bin    dev   home2           lib    libx32      mnt   root  snap  tmp  vmlinuz
boot   etc   initrd.img      lib32  lost+found  opt   run   srv   usr
cdrom  home  initrd.img.old  lib64  media       proc  sbin  sys   var
```

I can see my old files in `/home2/home/mahmood`. However, I don't know why I see `/etc` and `/home2/etc` for example. What is going on then?!

Comment: You have to copy the whole /home into the new partition. This is the problem. I suggest you to mount (using fstab) the old partition as /home2 and then you may copy al files into home2 into the new /home.

`cp -avp /home2/* /home`

After the copy is done and you verified the operation is correct you may remove the whole /home2 contents (but I think is better that the files deletion will be done after you tested  for some time that the new /home is ok) and then you may delete /home2 mount from the fstab file (or not delete it, so you will have it as a immediately disponible backup copy)

Comment: I want to know how to find the missing partition in order to mount that as home2.

Comment: I tried commenting `UUID=3ce518e8-955d-4b26-9dde-c3819d5906d6   /home    ext4    defaults   0   2` in `/etc/fstab`. However, it has no effect.

Comment: @SirJoBlack Please don't post answers as comments.  **;-)**  If you post it as an answer with a few step-by-step instructions and leave me a comment, I'll come back and upvote.  **0:-)** (go to tty1, dismount /home, remount as home2, copy, reboot and if all is well, mount old home and delete)  **Alternatively,** I can do as well...  **>:-)**

Comment: @mahmood, you may mount the old home using the device name instead of the UUID. `/dev/nvme0n1p2 /home2 ext4 defaults 0 2`. You also may decomment the other. In this way you will have both directory.

Comment: Please see the updated post. I can now see the old files, but there are some questions.

Comment: I've idea that you mounted the home where is mounted the root.

Comment: Ok! The problem is that the /home is not mounted, but is created under root.

Comment: In this case if you remove the new line you have inserted into fstab you see the old home.

Comment: Then  you may rename it as home2 and then re-insert the mountpoint for the new home into the fstab.

Comment: @mahmood I've written both cases into the answer.

Comment: That second bit about mounting the root partition in /home, don't do it (hopefully there a check, but if not it could break).

Comment: You need to use a bind mount. Some thing like `sudo mount --bind / /mnt`, then move stuff from `/mnt/home` to `/home`, then unmount the bind mount (`/sudo umount /mnt`). No need to put in fstab, as only temporary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create the new mountpoint /home the data are not moved from the previous /home to the new.

To solve the problem you have to use "simple" workarounds.

There are two cases:

**The first case** is when the old home was mounted in a partition by means the file fstab.

In this case you may operate as in the following lines:

You have to copy the whole /home into the new partition.

The first step is to ripristinate the old /home as /home2 inserting into the file fstab this line without removing the new line you have inserted

`/dev/nvme0n1p2 /home2 ext4 defaults 0 2`

The second step is to reboot your PC. In this way you will have both directories: /home (the new home) and /home2 (the old home)

**The second case** is when the /home directory is a real directory under /.

In this case you have to rename your /home as /home2 (before this you have to delete the new home line from fstab, if it is there, and reboot)

`sudo mv /home /home2`

Then you have to insert the new /home line into fstab and reboot.

The last step (in both cases) is to copy all files from home2 to home:

`sudo cp -apvr /home2/* /home`

In this way you will have the new /home and then may consider /home2 as a backup copy.

When you will be sure the new /home is correct you will be free to delete all files in /home2:

`sudo rm -rf /home2/*`

And then you will remove the /home2 line from the fstab files in the first case or delete the /home2 directory in the second case.

`sudo rm -rf /home2` # in the second case.

I suggest you to wait some time before to delete /home2.

Comment: @mahmood, I saw that I forgotten to indicate the option `-r` into the cp line. I've modified my answer. the option -r should copy all files including hidden files (that you may see using `ls -lad /home2/*` or `ls -lad /home/*`.

Comment: @mahmood. I'm not sure it's all correct. See if all hidden files has been copied for all users, using `ls -lad /home2/<username>/.* and ls -lad /home/<username>/.*` where <username> shall be substituted with the user you need to verify.